# Cannot invoke a simple object’s prototype function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I’m new to node and assume I’m missing something simple here. Essentially I have a class in the model file used to instantiate new object instances as follows:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
const getDb = require('../util/database').getDb;
const ObjectId = mongodb.ObjectId; // needed?

class User {
  constructor(email, password) { // removed , id
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
  }

  save() {
    const db = getDb();
    return db.collection('users').insertOne(this)
      .then(result => {
        console.log('save() result: ', result);
        return result;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('error: ', err)
      });
  }

  static findById(userId) {
    const db = getDb();
    return db
      .collection('users')
      .findOne({
        _id: new ObjectId(userId)
      })
      .then(user => {
        console.log(user);
        return user;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  static findByEm(em) {
    const db = getDb();
    return db.collection('users')
      .find({
        'email': em
      })
      .next()
      .then(user => {
        console.log('user find test: ', user)
        return user;
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error: ', err)
      });
  }
}
```

module.exports = User;

And the relevant part of my controller function is as follows:

```
exports.postReset = (req, res, next) => {
    crypto.randomBytes(32, (err, buffer) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.redirect('/reset');
        }
        const token = buffer.toString('hex');
        User.findByEm(req.body.email)
            .then(user => {
                if (!user) { // if there's no user - change to if user == null?
                    return res.render('auth/forgot-password', {
                        pageHead: 'Reset Password',
                        pageTitle: 'Reset Password Page',
                        pageIntro: 'No account with that email found.',
                        path: '/forgot-password'
                    });
                }
                user['resetToken'] = token;
                user['resetTokenExpiration'] = Date.now() + 3600000;
                console.log('userr: ', user);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
                return user.save(); // ERROR HERE: TypeError: user.save is not a function
                //return user.prototype.save();
            })
            .then(result => {
                res.redirect('/');
                transporter.sendMail({
                    from: '"Test" <test@gmail.com',
                    to: req.body.email,
                    subject: 'Password reset',
                    html: `
                        <p>You requested a new pasword.</p>
                        <p>Click the <a href="http://localhost:3000/forgot-password/${token}">link</a> to set a new password.</p>
                    `
                })
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    });
}
```

After submitting an email form, the function just searches the database to see if an entry with the same email already exists. If it does, it’s supposed to add two new properties `resetToken` and `resetTokenExpiration` and then update the entry in the database with these new properties.

The function successfully finds the user in the database, but for some reason I cannot get it to call the `save()` method as set in the class in the model file and logs this error:

```
TypeError: user.save is not a function
```

Why is it not calling the save function? It’s set in the class as a prototype function so it should theoretically be able to call it.

Thanks for any help here.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(user))` right before the save, what does that print?

Comment: it logs this: {"_id":"5f288f3a095536f5149d093c","email":"nick@nick.com","password":"$2a$12$8cZ6Uf75iu35uMQ4O1.BIO/nIzWEMHje1p237muQz9mxCOo12rJxW","resetToken":"a29ed1d4ac3fc4a9b0f7376a1b954b33f2154bc298170e9b46eecc7830b3336b","resetTokenExpiration":1596928305534}

Comment: All would work as you expect if the promise returned by `User.findByEm(req.body.email)` resolved to an instance of the `User` class. But it seems that isn't the case. Without seeing how that function is implemented, I can't say any more.

Comment: I'll add more code to my post

Comment: @user8758206 it would be especially helpful to see the definition of `findByEm()`

Comment: What is `User.findByEm`? The `class User` on which you defined your `save` method doesn't have that, are they two distinct classes with the same name?

Comment: it finds the user by their email address - I've updated my code in the post

Comment: And the findByEm method is a prototype function of the User class

Comment: @user8758206 Actually it's a `static` method not a prototype method

Comment: what's the difference?

Comment: Do any of the `console.log`s inside `findByEm` trigger? If so, which ones?

Comment: yes, it logs this one:
user find test:  {
  _id: 5f288f3a095536f5149d093c,
  email: 'nick@nick.com',
  password: '$2a$12$8cZ6Uf75iu35uMQ4O1.BIO/nIzWEMHje1p237muQz9mxCOo12rJxW'
}

Comment: Anyway, while I'm not too familiar with mongoDB, I don't see why the `findOne` method would return an instance of your `User` class - I assume it returns whatever object type the library uses to represent the record in your database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `findByEm` method returns a promise that is fulfilled with a database record, not an instance of your `User` class. It won't have the `.save` method therefore. You'll need to explicitly construct the instance and return that:

```
static findByEm(email) {
  return getDb().collection('users')
    .find({email})
    .next()
    .then(data => {
      console.log('user find test: ', data)
      return new User(data.email, data.password); // and id etc
//           ^^^^^^^^
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that makes sense!

Comment: Btw you might want to have a look at mongoose, a library that creates all these boilerplate methods for your model classes for you

Comment: The course I'm studying on Udemy covered mongoose, but I already created a project before it taught me it, hence why I haven't used a schema. By the way, your solution creates another entry in the DB rather than amending the entry currently in the database. Is there a way that it could just update the entry in the database? Otherwise there will be duplicate entries with the same email address. Mind you, then I assume the logic of constructing a new instance will be jeopardised

Comment: @user8758206 You mean when calling `.save()`? That's upon your implementation, which currently calls `insert`. Given the comment `// removed , id` I thought you had just omitted that from the sample code for the question, actually having more properties on your class, and that `save` would update the mongodb object with the instance's id.

Answer (score -1):

`findByEm` returns a promise, not a User object. So you need to change how you're handling that promise:

```js
User.findByEm(req.body.email)
            .then((res, err) => {
    // use res.user here
```

Alternatively, you can choose to "await" the `db.collection.find` inside `findByEm` and make `findByEm` an async function.

```
static async findByEm(em) {
    const db = getDb();
    return await db.collection('users')
      .find({
        'email': em
      })
      .next()
      .then(user => {
        console.log('user find test: ', user)
        return user;
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error: ', err)
      });
  }
```

Then your default code that expects a `User` object would work.

Comment: What's the actual difference between returning a promise vs a User object? I thought the code I had (i.e. the findByEm) method found the user and returned that. I tried replacing my findByEm with your async code but it returns the same 'TypeError: user.save is not a function' error

Comment: Do you know if there's a better way that I can build a demo for everyone to see? I know you're limited by only the code I provide. I'd love to build a demo somehow that gives you visibility to all of my code and would allow you to run tests on it etc

Comment: Promises need to be awaited or resolved in order to actually yield the User value.